# Этимология слов с корнем "терр", "терра"

Tags: этимология

Верно ли, что слово  "терраса" имеет происхождение от корня terra - земля, "террариум" - участок, отгороженный для змей, тоже имеет корнем "терра"? Слово "террор" тоже содержит сочетание "терр", но его значение сильно отличается от предыдущих. Какова этимология данного слова "террор"?

Answer (score 2):

Оба слова имеют латинские корни. Терраса от  terra - земля, а террор от terror - страх, ужас.

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что в русском языке эти слова надо считать просто созвучными.

Попробую объясниться. Формулируя вопрос, вы упустили важную деталь. Слова эти заимствованные и terra - корень в латинском языке, выделять его в русском можно только с большими оговорками. Точно так же "террор" от латинского terror - страх, ужас. И непонятно, что считать корнем в русском.
Обычно в таких случаях исследование сравнительной этимологии заканчивается, поскольку это уже сфера другого языка. Да и родственность слов в языке-источнике не означает их родственности в языке-мишени.

Конечно, будь родстенность слов в латинском установлена, я бы эту информацию не скрыл. Но мне на этот счёт ничего неизвестно, ни доказать, ни опровергнуть не представляется возможным. Возможно специалист по латинскому, если таковой здесь объявится, уточнит, но похоже, что концов и в латинском не найти.

Comment: Я думаю, и в латинском они не родственны: слишком уж разные значения. А определение корня (в общем языкознании. не только в русистике) предполагает наличие общности в значении.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутые ответы. 
Вопрос еще косвенно связан с этимологией русского варианта имени Екатерина и иногда встречающегося на Западе имени Террина, в которых тоже есть данное сочетание "тер" или "терр". Само имя греческого Екатерина происхождения, в оригинале и в латинской транслитерации записывается по-другому, а точных гипотез происхождения и значения этого имени неизвестно.

Comment: "Екатерина" - с греческого "вечно чистая". Вам объяснит любой даже не батюшка, а дьячок, хоть отдаленно учившийся греческому. 
Никаких других "гипотез" я не рассматривал и не собираюсь рассматривать.

Answer (score 1):

> Верно ли, что слово "терраса" имеет происхождение от корня terra - земля, "террариум" - участок, отгороженный для змей, тоже имеет корнем "терра"?

Да, верно. Эти слова происходят от лат. слова terra -- земля.

Terra, в свою очередь, происходит от праиндоевропейского (дальше буду  сокращать как ПИЕ) ***ters*** -- сухой.
Источник на англ.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European/ters-

От этого же ПИЕ *ters* происходит, например, ирландское слово tir (земля, страна, территория, грунт); от древнего кельтского tiros -- сухая земля, в противоположность озеру или морю.
[Источник](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tir)

Сравните с русским словом "суша". А также словом "сухопутный",  в противоположность морскому. Море, кстати, тоже очень древнее слово.

Также от ПИЕ ters происходит англ. thirsty и санскр. trsyati (более точное написание по ссылке). Оба слова переводятся одинаково --  жаждать, томиться жаждою
[с санскр. на англ.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF#Sanskrit)

Греч. τέρσομαι - tersomai - быть (или становиться) сухим, высыхать

Вспоминается русское разговорное "сушняк" или "сушит" :-) (когда пить хочется).

**Итак, слова "терраса" и "террариум" происходят от латинского слова "терра". А терра -- это сухая земля, в противоположность озеру или морю.**

- - 

> Слово "террор" тоже содержит сочетание "терр", но его значение сильно отличается от предыдущих. Какова этимология данного слова "террор"?

Лат. terror от лат. terrere — пугать, ужасать, запугивать. Это слово происходит от другого ПИЕ корня, не от того, что terra -- суша -- ters.
Оно происходит от ПИЕ tres -- дрожать. Другой похожий ПИЕ корень -- trem- с тем же значением. По-видимому, общий корень у них ПИЕ tre- трясти, встряхивать.
[Источник на англ.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terror)

Здесь уже проще подобрать славянские аналоги. От ПИЕ tres- -- древнеславянск. tręs- -- русск. тряс-.

Одно из значений русского слова "трясти" -- приводить в дрожь.
Смотрим, если угодно, значения русского "трясти". [link text](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/трясти)
Пункт 2 по приведённой ссылке -- **приводить в дрожь. Это, как мне кажется, и есть изначальное значение слова "террор".**

**P.S.** Не по теме. Зная украинск. язык, мне интересно было узнать, что трем- очень древний, ещё ПИЕ, корень. Есть укр. слово тремтiти -- дрожать. ( А также лит. trìmti, лат. tremo и другие похожие).

Comment: Спасибо за подробный комментарий.
"Другой похожий ПИЕ корень -- trem- с тем же значением. По-видимому, общий корень у них ПИЕ tre- трясти, встряхивать." - отсюда, наверное, происходит "тремор" (лат. tremor — дрожание).

Comment: >отсюда, наверное, происходит "тремор" (лат. tremor — дрожание).

Да, отсюда.